# validate form field to only use geocomplete values

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am using the jQuery geocomplete plugin in a Ruby on Rails application.  I am able to have the form field pre-populate with suggested fields which is working correctly but I want the user to only be able to select fields that are available in that dropdown only.  Users should not be able to type in an actual value.

Here is my form field:

```
<%= f.text_field :location, placeholder: 'Location (e.g. Toronto, ON, Canada)', :required => true, data: { :autocomplete => "off", 
                          :validation => "required",
                          "validation-error-msg" => "This field is required."
                        }, class: 'cool-input locaton-input' %>
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(".locaton-input").geocomplete({ types: ['(cities)'] });
```

How can I validate the field to only use the values that are received from geocomplete?